# Why aren't the radio buttons displayed when I use MaterialAlertDialogBuilder?

Tags: android-studio, material-design

The Code A is based the [article](https://material.io/components/dialogs/android#confirmation-dialog).

And I get Image A  when I run Code A, it seems that all the radio buttons aren't displayed .

What's wrong with my code?

**Code A**

```
  val singleItems = arrayOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
        val checkedItem = 1

        val context = LocalContext.current

        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setNeutralButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->
            }
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
            }
            .setSingleChoiceItems(singleItems, checkedItem) { dialog, which ->

            }
           .show()
```

**themes.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">   
    <style name="Theme.SoundMeter" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">     
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
       
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
       
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
     
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.SoundMeter.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.SoundMeter.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.SoundMeter.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

**Image A**

[image]

Comment: Try to change the Theme color for alert dialog. May be the inactive radio button is white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried with the MaterialAlertDialogBuilder still the same issue.
So I created the dialog using the Dialog Composable

```
@Composable
fun CustomDialog(
title: String = "Title",
onDismiss: (() -> Unit)? = {},
radioItems: List<String> = listOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"),
positiveAction: () -> Unit = {},
negativeAction: () -> Unit = {},
positiveText: String = "Ok",
cancelledText: String = "Cancel",
selectedIndex: MutableState<Int> = mutableStateOf(1),
changeIndex: (Int) -> Unit = { index -> selectedIndex.value = index }
) {
   Dialog(onDismissRequest = { onDismiss?.invoke() }) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White)) {
        Text(
            text = title,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp, start = 16.dp,  bottom = 16.dp),
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )

        radioItems.forEachIndexed { index, radioText ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().clickable { changeIndex(index) },
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                RadioButton(
                    selected = index == selectedIndex.value,
                    colors = RadioButtonDefaults.colors(selectedColor = Color.Blue),
                    onClick = { changeIndex(index) }
                )

                Text(text = radioText, modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp))
            }
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            OutlinedButton(
                onClick = {
                    negativeAction()
                    onDismiss?.invoke()
                },
                border = BorderStroke(0.dp, Color.Transparent),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Transparent)
            ) { Text(text = cancelledText, color = Color.Red) }

            OutlinedButton(
                onClick = {
                    positiveAction()
                    onDismiss?.invoke()
                },
                border = BorderStroke(0.dp, Color.Transparent),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Transparent)
            ) { Text(text = positiveText, color = Color.Blue) }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyRlP.jpg)